# throw and catch error if element is not found

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, selenium-chromedriver

I've made a small selenium project which just clicks on different elements.
If an element does not exist, i want to immediately throw an error and close.
At the moment, my test file is just stuck at the point the error occures.

```js
try {

  client
  .init()
  .url('https://testpage123.com')

  .click('#existing_element1')
  .click('#not_existing_element')
  .catch(err => {
    throw new Error('element not found')
  })
  
  .click('#existing_element2')
  .click('#existing_element3')

}
catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: whooops , edited!